# How to set HttpOnly Cookie in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cookies, webview

Is it possible to pass **HttpOnly** Cookie to Android WebView (**Chromium**)?

I try to use:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().acceptCookie();
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, cookieData);
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true)
```

But it not work for me. I don't know if *setCookie* works with HttpOnly.